# Rails 6 Capistrano Deployment - Webpacker Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, capistrano3

When I try to deploy my Rails 6 application via Capistrano 3, until a few days everything worked fine.

Now, when my application got bigger (more assets etc.) I decided to precompile my assets locally, cause the remote server just has 2 GB RAM. 
If I let Capistrano do the compiling, it takes ages (it doesn't even finish, I waited like 5 hours), then I aborted it. There is no error or something, it just hangs at "Compiling ..."

So I found a task that compiles my assets locally, it is working through:

```
# lib/capistrano/tasks/precompile.rake
    namespace :deploy do
      namespace :assets do

        desc 'Precompile assets locally and upload to server'
        task :precompile_locally_copy do
          on roles(:app) do
            run_locally do
              with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
                execute 'rake assets:precompile'
              end
            end

            execute "cd #{release_path} && mkdir public" rescue nil
            execute "cd #{release_path} && mkdir public/assets" rescue nil
            execute 'rm -rf public/assets/*'

            upload! 'public/assets', "#{release_path}/public", recursive: true

          end
        end
      end
    end
```

This is my deploy-file:

```
# config/deploy.rb

lock "~> 3.11.2"

set :application, "webmenue"
set :repo_url, "git@dinolab.ges.thm.de:Abschlussarbeiten/webmenue_2019.git"

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
append :linked_files, "config/master.key", "config/database.yml"

namespace :deploy do
    namespace :check do
      before :linked_files, :set_master_key do
        on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 10 do
          unless test("[ -f #{shared_path}/config/master.key ]")
            upload! 'config/master.key', "#{shared_path}/config/master.key"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end

# before "assets:precompile", "deploy:yarn_install"
# namespace :deploy do
#   desc "Run rake yarn install"
#   task :yarn_install do
#     on roles(:web) do
#       within release_path do
#         execute("cd #{release_path} && yarn install --silent --no-progress --no-audit --no-optional")
#       end
#     end
#   end
# end

after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:assets:precompile_locally_copy'

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'node_modules', 'public/packs'

# Crono Options
set :crono_pid, -> { File.join(shared_path, 'tmp', 'pids', 'crono.pid') }
set :crono_env, -> { fetch(:rack_env, fetch(:rails_env, fetch(:stage))) }
set :crono_log, -> { File.join(shared_path, 'log', 'crono.log') }
set :crono_role, -> { :app }

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

Here is my production.rb:

```
# config/environments/production.rb
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress CSS using a preprocessor.
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.precompile += ['application.scss', 'application.js']


  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain.
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "WebMenue_New_production"

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Inserts middleware to perform automatic connection switching.
  # The `database_selector` hash is used to pass options to the DatabaseSelector
  # middleware. The `delay` is used to determine how long to wait after a write
  # to send a subsequent read to the primary.
  #
  # The `database_resolver` class is used by the middleware to determine which
  # database is appropriate to use based on the time delay.
  #
  # The `database_resolver_context` class is used by the middleware to set
  # timestamps for the last write to the primary. The resolver uses the context
  # class timestamps to determine how long to wait before reading from the
  # replica.
  #
  # By default Rails will store a last write timestamp in the session. The
  # DatabaseSelector middleware is designed as such you can define your own
  # strategy for connection switching and pass that into the middleware through
  # these configuration options.
  # config.active_record.database_selector = { delay: 2.seconds }
  # config.active_record.database_resolver = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  # config.active_record.database_resolver_context = ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver::Session
end
```

As I said the task is working, but my application still uses the old application.js file, even though the new .sprockets-manifest--file is uploaded. So I thought maybe I have to upload my packs-folder aswell, but it has grown relatively large during the time and I symlinked it anyway (linked_dirs in deploy.rb), but when I explore that folder with an SSH-Client it's still the old one.

I don't really know what to do, I don't even know why Capistrano isn't progressing in Compiling cause there is no error.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? Should I upload the whole packs-folder?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if you wait 5 hours, it means the connection is lost

Comment: I faced this problem when my production server's RAM was just 16GB, so to fix it i created a new swapfile with a new space of 16GB. And after that things were back to normal